# How can you add an reoccuring appointment at the last day of every month in the calendar

Tags: calendar

Is there a way to add a reoccuring appointment to the calender in Android at the **last day of every month** ?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.  Here is what I ended up doing.  Maybe it will work for you:  In my case, I wanted an appointment to appear at a specified time on the last day of the month and remind me 1 hour early.  I ended up making my appointment on the 1st day of every month and then setting reminders to SMS message me 25 hours early and 24 hours early, respectively.

It seems that if you want it exactly on the last day, most people resort to setting up 12 separate appointments, one for each month, that repeat annually.  But, then you'll have that 29th day of February to deal with as was the case this year.  Mine worked anyway...

Comment: Yes, that is how I am doing it at the moment (1st of month and reminder one day earlier). Just thought there should be an easier way.

Comment: @Edelcom: Why mess with something that works... As long as you don't have an option that sais "Last day of month", you have to make the best of it ;-)

Comment: @awe : You are correct, of course. But is seemed such a logical option that I find it strange it is not included. Let's say you have to pay your rent in the last month, or you have to go to the bank to get your bank statements before a new month is started. I can think of several reasons why a 'last day of the month' option should be handy. I was just hoping I missed something.

Comment: Maybe you could ask if there is a calendar app on the market available that has this option.